# Multiple Login page Template php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to let super admin choose his user's  login page template from available template in my script , if I have temp1 , temp2,temp3 for login page  , how can I allow super admin to select one template for them  , and when one user trying to access login page the template which choose by super admin will display , how can I do that using php , mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, have a small table called `login_template` :

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ID |  NAME  |         PATH             | ACTIVE |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Temp1  | form/login/template1.php |   0    |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | Temp2  | form/login/template2.php |   1    |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| 3  | Temp3  | form/login/template3.php |   0    |
|-------------------------------------------------|
```

Then, you need to display all the entries of your `login_template` table in order to let the super admin choose which template he wants to activate.

The easiest solution for that should be to create a new form with a radio button next to each entry. The super admin will then click on a radio button and submit the form in order to choose a template.

When the form is submitted, you retrieve the `ID` of the template selected by the admin, and you enable this template in your database (and of course disable the old template selected).

Good luck !